# Why is my country/city not acknowledged in the clock location selection?

Tags: indicator

I just found out as a fresh Ubuntu user, that apparently I don't live in Israel, according to the clock's location I live in "Mikveh Israel"...
What The H?!
I live in the state of **Israel** and as far as I am aware of, that's it's name.

I am very surprised to see this kind of misinformation in such a well built system and grand community and it would be only reasonable to fix this mistake.

Any one can explain that to me?

Comment: I'm not as up-to-date on my timezones as I could be, but I believe Israel is a single timezone, in which case this works fine. http://i.stack.imgur.com/yN0sy.png

Comment: I've edited your title to be more general as this isn't country related as such, it all just depends on who has submitted what information about a specific country.

Comment: Ubuntu as any other distro is mainly maintained by the large free help of people like you and me. If you find a bug or any misinformation you can help the community with it by providing the correct information for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The location database for 11.04 and newer is handled by the ubuntu-geoname package, it's a community contributed set of data. If it's incorrect for your country then you can submit data to it to be included, instructions to doing that is available here:

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-geonames
- [How do I report a bug?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug)

For 10.10 and older (anything running gnome-panel), you can report a bug for libgweather:

- http://live.gnome.org/LibGWeather/ImprovingLocations

Comment: OK every one thanks a bunch! i will get right to work and start inputing as much info as i can and ditch as much mistakes as i can in the process.